# Why is objects accelerating in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pygame

In my, for-loop I have a statement saying `p.x -= p.vel`. Apparently this causes the object to accelerate for each object on the screen. If I pop the object from the list it doesn't accelerate as much but it still speeds up a bit. How can I fix this? The program is written with pygame

The game is basically a flappy bird game and it's the pipes that are accelerating but I want them to move in the same speed all the time

Here are the class and the variables

```
    def __init__(self, x, width):
        self.bottom_height = random.randint(50, 400)
        self.top_height = screen_height - 175 - self.bottom_height
        self.width = width

        self.bottom_y = screen_height - self.bottom_height
        self.top_y = 0
        self.x = x

        self.vel = 2.5

        self.pipes = []
```

Here are the functions

```
    def spawn(self):
        for p in pipe.pipes:
            if bird.x == p.x:
                pipe.pipes.append(Pipe(pipe.x, pipe. width))

    def move(self):
        self.spawn()
        for p in pipe.pipes:
            if 0 - p.width < p.x < screen_width + 50:
                p.x -= p.vel
            else:
                pipe.pipes.pop(pipe.pipes.index(p))
```

Comment: What accelerates? The library you're using (pygame?) would be infinitely more useful than "oop" and "loops" as tags

Comment: The pipes in the game (flappy bird).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
for p in pipe.pipes:
    if 0 - p.width < p.x < screen_width + 50:
        p.x -= p.vel
    else:
        pipe.pipes.pop(pipe.pipes.index(p))
```

You are iterating on a list and while iterating on it you're removing elements from it.

Take this example, derived from your code:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in s:
    print(i)
    s.pop(s.index(i))
```

What do you expect the output to be? Hint: it's not going to be `1 2 3 4 5`.

To fix this you can either loop over the list, keep track in another list which elements you want to remove and remove them after the loop, or loop over a copy of the list and remove the elements from the original one every time you need.

Also, it's going to be faster if you save the index of the element to remove.

Something like (untested!):

```
def move(self):
    self.spawn()
    index_to_remove = []
    for i in range(len(pipe.pipes)):
        if 0 - p.width < p.x < screen_width + 50:
            p.x -= p.vel
        else:
            index_to_remove.append(i)
    for index in index_to_remove:
        del pipe.pipes[index]
```

Comment: still speeding up and getting: ```IndexError: list assignment index out of range```

Comment: Yes, you're doing the same thing in that piece of code, you just need to apply the same idea (keep track of the index to remove and do it after the loop)